# Eclipse java web project manual set lib folder in WEB-INF

Tags: java, eclipse, web-services, svn

I checked out a project from svn. The project have a folder named as "ws" which contains WebContent folder. But the lib folder is outside the WebContent folder and under another folder under "ws" folder. I found out I have to move the lib folder to WEB-INF folder in WebContent folder, so eclipse can find the libraries I need.

Would anyone show me how to manually set the path so eclipse can load the libraries from the original lib without moving the lib to WEB-INF?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can edit the Deployment Assembly which controls how the app deployment is assembled. Right-click the project and select **Properties**; select **Deployment Assembly** and then use **Add...** to include your project's libraries (JARs) in the *deployed* `WEB-INF/lib` folder.

If you've already included the libraries  on the project Build Path, there's an option in the Add... dialog to include them directly. Otherwise you can just add a folder itself.

[image]

Comment: Thanks. But it did not work. I am actually trying to let the eclipse looking for libraries that are supposed to be in WEB-INF/lib from another folder. How would I tell eclipse to do that.

Comment: Where are those libraries stored currently? Are they on your project's Build Path already?

Comment: Yes. I tried to put them on build path. Originally those libraries are in some folder not the WEB-INF/lib. I tried to include them in the build path. But to get it work, I have to copy the libraries to WEB-INF/lib. I am thinking it might because the eclipse is looking for libraries from WEB-INF/lib, but I don't know how to tell eclipse to look somewhere else like where the libraries originally are?

Comment: Look at my answer again carefully, it tells you how to include libraries from other locations in the deployed app (Eclipse calls it the Deployment Assembly, the package that is constructed by Eclipse to deploy your app). The second part of my answer shows how to include libraries that are already on your project's Build Path.

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day :)